# I am not able to create a workflow in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I use Create Workflow on the ribbon which takes me to Designer. I am able to select a List workflow (part of what I am trying to acieve). I have tried to create it every available way but the workflow does not show up in designer or on the site

Comment: Have you tried clearing the local cache files? This seemed to work for me https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/154513

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the steps described in this [MSDN instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554671.aspx)?

**EDIT**

As you are unable to see SharePoint 2013 as Platform Type, please find the note from the documentation:

> If you do not see SharePoint 2013 Workflow as an available platform
>   type then Workflow Manager is not configured to work with the
>   SharePoint Server 2013 farm.

Check out the steps for [Installing and configuring workflow for SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx) and [Installing and Configuring Workflow Manager 1.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193478.aspx)

Comment: I have an installation of SP 2013 and SPD 2013. I am not able to see SP 2013 in the Platform Type. I believe this is an issue. I am not sure why it is missing. Any suggestions?